# Using jQuery the word appears and disappears?

Tags: jquery

In jquery, I have a problem. There is a word `welcome` that should appear for 10 seconds.

After 10 seconds this should disappeared and another word `bye` should appear for another 10 seconds this should continued like a cycling process.

Can anyone help me out with this problem????

Comment: i have tried with using animate(), fadein() , fadeOut() & delay() functions. i'm not getting correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text is within in `div#text`

```
function changeText() {
    if ($("div#text").text() == 'welcome') {
        $("div#text").text('bye');
    } else {
        $("div#text").text('welcome');
    }
}

setInterval(changeText, 10000);
```

This does not include any type of animation, just changes the text.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also try this :( fadein() , fadeOut())**

```
$(function() {
        setInterval('Welcome()', 1000);
    })

    function Welcome() {        
        $('#msg').fadeIn(2000, function() {
            $('#msg').html("Welcome").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("bye")
            })
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeText() {
    var _text = $("#text");

    _text.fadeOut(500, function () {
    if (_text.text() == 'welcome') {
        _text.text('bye');
    } else {
        _text.text('welcome');
    }
        _text.fadeIn(500);
    });

}
changeText();
setInterval(changeText, 10000);
```

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s2rdD/

Answer (score -1):

Due to the lack of detail (and a slight smell of homework) I'm only going to give very general advice.

You need to do something after a time interval. jQuery doesn't have that built in, but it's simple enough to do without it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

It sounds like you need to update text, jQuery can do that: http://api.jquery.com/text/

It is imperative to lean Javascript even while using jQuery. A good book can help there, something along the lines of this one. [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527/ref=pd_sim_b_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)

Strangely enough, the two answers that were posted while I was writing these have the exact same code, down to formatting and naming. And as such, they both contain a mistake.